# How to split a column data with no separator in R

Tags: r

I have a dataset, where the data is in the format of 20110528 i.e. YYYYMMDD.
I want to split the data as YYYY MM DD. 
can anyone help, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can do this with `extract` from `tidyr`

```
library(tidyr)
extract(df1, date, into = c("Year", "Month", "Day"), "(.{4})(.{2})(.{2})")
```

---

Or another option is `read.csv`

```
cbind(df1, read.csv(text=sub("(.{4})(.{2})(.{2})", "\\1,\\2,\\3",
     df1$date), header=FALSE, col.names = c("Year", "Month", "Day")))
```

Comment: I like using base R when possible. Thus, I like your second option more. I point this out so the OP doesn't think it's necessary to use tidyr.